# How can I fit MultiLabelBinarizer correctly?

Tags: scikit-learn, multilabel-classification

I have some labels (A,B,C,H,H1,H2 etc).However when I fit MultiLabelBinarizer, it splits H1 into H and 1.
Can someone tell me if there's a solution to this problem besides changing the H1 label into another label.
Thank you

```
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()


labels = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['LABELS']),columns=mlb.classes_)
```

Comment: Can you provide your code that labels are split?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add all possible labels. This means that you should have saved the possible labels in a column of an excel file. That's my case anyway.

```
tags = pd.read_excel('/content/multi_labels.xlsx')
unique_tags = tags.Name.unique()
#one_hot_encode
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(classes=unique_tags)
labels = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['LABELS']),columns=mlb.classes_)
```